# "redeem" in a TED talk of Kelly McGonigal

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I cannot figure out what the following sentence means.

> Now I said I have over a decade of demonizing stress to redeem myself from, so we are going to do one more intervention.

Especially "stress to redeem myself from" is not clear.

I think this as "stress to save myself from".
But I am not confident.

Comment: I haven't seen the talk, but it could mean "I have been demonizing stress for more than ten years, but it turns out that stress is a good thing, or not as bad as I thought it was, and I was wrong to demonize it, and so I must redeem myself (make amends) for doing that.

Answer (score 2):

[Just as I thought](http://news.stanford.edu/2015/05/07/stress-embrace-mcgonigal-050715/). The speaker argues that we should "embrace stress", accept it as a good thing.

> **Embracing stress is more important than reducing stress, Stanford psychologist says**
>
> *Stanford psychologist Kelly McGonigal talks about new research indicating that stress can make us stronger, smarter and happier – if
>   we learn how to open our minds to it.*

So **redeem myself** there means to take action to make amends for a misdeed or a wrong that one has committed.